# Silverstripe 3.4 sqlquery many-many

Tags: silverstripe

I am trying to get Staffs from a many_many relation.

Daisy is in Office AND in Workshop

Dagobert is in Office

Daisy and Dagobert should appear in Impressum (AdImpressum).

In my relation-table Daisy appears two times (Offie, Workshop) with different **SortOrder-value.(One for Office, one for Workshop)**

What i get now is **Donald with SortOrder 1**
and **Daisy with SortOrder 1**

> How has my Query to be altered to get all Staffs with AdImpressum 1 
>   with a unique SortOrder-value?

```
StaffCatObject


ID |   ClassName    | CatOrder |   Name   |

1  | StaffCatObject |     1    |  OFFICE  |
2  | StaffCatObject |     2    | WORKSHOP |



Staff

ID | ClassName  |    Name   |  AdImpressum  |

1  |    Staff   |   Daisy   |       1       |
2  |    Staff   |   Donald  |       0       |
3  |    Staff   |  Dagobert |       1       |
4  |    Staff   |   Gustav  |       0       |
5  |    Staff   |   Daniel  |       0       |



StaffCatObject_Staffs

ID |StaffCatObjectID | StaffID | SortOrder | Display |

1  |        1        |    1    |     1     |    1    | (=Daisy)
3  |        1        |    3    |     3     |    1    |
4  |        2        |    2    |     1     |    1    | (=Donald)
5  |        1        |    4    |     2     |    1    |
8  |        2        |    1    |     2     |    1    | (=Daisy)
….
```

my function:

```
public function getImpressumStaff(){

    $sqlQuery = new SQLSelect();
    //$sqlQuery->select = array('DISTINCT StaffID, StaffCatObject_Staffs.SortOrder, StaffCatObjectID, Display, StaffCatObject_Staffs.ID');
    $sqlQuery->from = array('StaffCatObject_Staffs');
    $sqlQuery->addWhere('"Display" = 1');
    $sqlQuery->addLeftJoin('StaffCatObject', '"StaffCatObject"."ID" = "StaffCatObject"."ID"');
    $sqlQuery->addLeftJoin('Staff', '"Staff"."ID" = "StaffCatObject_Staffs"."StaffID"');
    $sqlQuery->addWhere('"AdImpressum" = 1');
    $sqlQuery->setOrderBy('StaffCatObject.SortOrder');

    //$sqlQuery->setOrderBy('StaffCatObject_Staffs.SortOrder');
    //$sqlQuery->setGroupBy('StaffCatObject_Staffs.StaffID');
    //$sqlQuery->setGroupBy('StaffCatObject_Staffs.SortOrder ASC');

    $sqlQuery->setGroupBy('StaffCatObject_Staffs.StaffCatObjectID');
    $result = $sqlQuery->execute();

    $returnedRecords = new ArrayList();
    foreach($result as $row) { 
        $returnedRecords->push(new ArrayData($row)); 
        //print_r($row);
    }
    return $returnedRecords;
}
```

Thanks.Sepp.

Answer (score 0):

`SortOrder` is unique for the same Staff category. So you need to add additional filter.

Your query can answer the questions:

- "What staff in the Office should appear in Impressum?"
- "What staff in the Workshop should appear in Impressum?"

Otherwise `SortOrder` field is not related.